# Tform.create (owner) in a dll application

Tags: forms, delphi

When a new form is created Delphi expects either  'Application', 'self', or 'nil' as an argument to define the owner. But what happens  when the form is in a dll rather than an independent (vcl) application? Clearly 'nil' is handled by the code written in the dll. However, I am unclear if 'Application' or 'self' will properly handle the 'form.free' operations if the form is created in a dll. If so when, is the form freed?

Comment: Expect much bigger challenges implementing a VCL form inside of a DLL. The `Application` will not be the same as the one in the application.

Comment: "*Delphi expects either 'Application', 'self', or 'nil' as an argument to define the owner*" - it has no such expectation.  You can use *any* `TComponent` object as the `Owner`, if not `nil`.  But, if you do specify `nil`, you are responsible for freeing the created object yourself when you are done using it.

Comment: Why oh why would anyone want to implement a form in a (normal) DLL? For such purposes, packages (BPLs) are much better suited. None of the problems you face with DLLs.

Comment: @rudy There are times. For instance, suppose you write a COM add in for an office app.

Comment: @rudy The dll is serving as a macro extension of a graphic CAD program.  The macros can use popup forms to manage data extracted from the program and to define new entities to add to the drawing files.  Delphi packages are not recognized.  The dlls are operated by the Cad program exporting only one function called 'Name'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When a new form is created Delphi expects either 'Application', 'self', or 'nil' as an argument to define the owner.

This is not correct. Any component can be supplied as the owner and the owned component is destroyed when its owner is destroyed.

> I am unclear if 'Application' or 'self' will properly handle the 'form.free' operations if the form is created in a dll. If so when, is the form freed?

In both cases, the form will be destroyed when the owner is destroyed. So the question becomes, quite simply, when is the owner destroyed. To which the answer is:

- **Application**: when the DLL is unloaded. In a DLL, there is an `Application` object, but its lifetime is tied to that of the DLL rather than the executable, as would be the case in a VCL executable module.
- **Self**: whenever `Self` is destroyed, and only you know that because only you know what `Self` is.

Comment: Thanks, I assume there is no simple way to determine if the program has unloaded the dll. My best option in this case would be to use 'nil' and handle freeing the form myself.

Comment: @Ashlar Sure there is. If you dynamically load the DLL, then you would also be the one responsible for unloading it too. So you would be the one who knows. Unless of course your DLL is loaded by a third-party application, which wasn't clear in your question. If that's the case, then I'd expect the caller to have a mechanism to unload/release memory, if it was designed correctly anyway. Some developers assume that you have garbage collection, and provide no means to release it.

Comment: @Jerry Unit finalisation happens at DLL unload time, for just one way to detect this without any cooperation.

Comment: @Ashlar if you want advice and guidance then we'd need to know how the dll is intended to be used and hosted.

Comment: @David Indeed true, just I was assuming this whole time that DLL will be hosted by OP's very own application, but a comment up above says otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the question. I do not have access to into the program that calls the dll, hence my concern whether the dll is being unloaded properly.